# Set "autocomplete" property of Xpages form

Tags: xpages

I need to set the 'autocomplete' property of the form in my Xpage. I know how to set it on fields, but I need to completely prevent the browser from autofilling my forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `<xp:form>` to your XPage and set property `autocomplete="off"`:

```xml
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:form autocomplete="off">
        <xp:inputText>
            ...
        </xp:inputText>
        ...
    </xp:form>
</xp:view>
```

This will render the `<form...>` with autocomplete property:

```xml
<body class="xspView tundra">
<form id="view:_id2" method="post" action="/XPages/Stacky2.nsf/a.xsp" class="xspForm"
       enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
```

This prevents the browser from autofilling of all fields on your form.

Comment: When I add xp:form on my xpages a weird exception is thrown:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor231.invoke(Unknown Source)...

Comment: I also think this should be used with createForm="false" but that also didn't work (same exception as above)

Comment: This simple Xpages does not work also. Whenever I add xp:form that is does not work anymore. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
 <xp:form autocomplete="off">
  <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
 </xp:form>
</xp:view>

Comment: I'm using 9.0.1FP2. The 'autocomplete' property exists in xp:form in this version. I think this is the correct way to solve my problem but somhow it does not work at all anymore.

Comment: I tested it on 9.0.1 FP1. Does it work if you create a new database with just this test XPage?

Comment: New database works! Thanks. Now I'll try to figure out what the problem is with my current database... thanks again.

Comment: Just found out what was causing the problem. I had this inside my theme ;-)  <control>
  <name>ViewRoot</name>
  <property>
   <name>createForm</name>
   <value>true</value>
  </property>
 </control>